# Conditional Logic to Determine Correct Status String

Tags: java, design-patterns

There is a status variable in a Java application that can be set to one of many statutes, depending on many conditions. The status field is a String. When a condition is met, the status should be returned immediately, as follows:

e.g

```
String status = "";

if (condition1) {
  return "STATUS_1";
} else if (condition2) {
  return "STATUS_2";
} else if (condition3) {
  return "STATUS_3";
} else if (condition4) {
  return "STATUS_4";
}
...
else if (condition10) {
  return "STATUS_10";
}
```

I've considered which pattern would be best to make this code more SOLID... e.g. if a new condition is required then this class would need to edited to add the new condition, which would break the open / closed SOLID principle

I've looked at the Strategy Pattern, in particular "Replace Conditional Logic with Strategy", however that seems more appropriate when you want to decide on just one calculation / operation to use... My scenario does not seem to fit the Strategy Pattern as my logic determines the status, rather than determining which individual operation to execute - I need to run all the conditions until one is true

I wondered if the following pattern could work...

Have an interface as follows

```
public interace StatusCondition {
  boolean condition(Context context);
  String getStatus();
}
```

With an implementation as follows:

```
public class StatusAStatusCondition implements StatusCondition {

  boolean condition(Context context){
    return context.getValue1() == 0 && context.getValue2().equals("A");
  }

  String getStatus(){
    return "STATUS_A";
  }
}
```

This would allow a list of StatusCondition classes to be executed in order and return the status of the first StatusCondition where the condition() method returns true. e.g:

```
public String getStatus(List<StatusCondition> statusConditions) {
  for (StatusCondition statusCondition : statusConditions) {
    if (statusCondition.condition()) {
      return statusCondition.getStatus();
    }
  }
  return "";
}


usage:

List<StatusCondition> statusConditions = new ArrayList<>();
statusConditions.add(statusAStatusCondition);
statusConditions.add(statusBStatusCondition);
statusConditions.add(statusCStatusCondition);
statusConditions.add(statusDStatusCondition);
statusConditions.add(statusEStatusCondition);
statusConditions.add(statusFStatusCondition);
...

String status = getStatus(statusConditions);
```

To me this solves the open closed principle issue and also ensures the implementations are single responsibility... My question is, how could this pattern i've suggested be improved, or is there a pattern better suited to my scenario?

Comment: `if a new condition is required then this class would need to edited to add the new condition, which would break the open / closed SOLID principle` no, it does not break Open/Closed

Comment: So you would create ten different classes each with the same two methods? I think that would violate the DRY principle. Why not just create a `Map` of the conditions and status?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your first "if/else if" version.  If a coworker wants to add a status/condition later which method do you think would be easier for him/her to understand?  That being said, I suspect this question might be too opinion based for this site.

Comment: @IłyaBursov Yes it does. O/C states you should never modify published code. If the function this logic resides in has already been published, you'd violate O/C by modifying already published code to add another condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are absolutely correct that the original if/else ladder violates the Open/Closed Principle. Second, converting the status value to an interface is exactly the right step to take, to move away from [stringly-typed programming](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped). Third, your solution is essentially the [Chain of Responsibility Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility). It's an excellent solution to this problem. In summary, your instincts are spot on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One concern i have is around unit testing. Obviously there is value in testing the whole chain of commands in order to ensure the correct status is returned. However,  unit testing best practise suggests testing a class in isolation and mocking the dependencies. However, i’d lose the evaluation of the logic in each implementation if i mocked those classes. Is it reasonable to allow a unit test to run the actual code in the StatusCondition classes? Otherwise i guess i could leave this part to integration tests and test my individual implementations separately

Comment: Intuitively, you may think each link in the chain is a unit and any combination of links is an integration. That's not actually how Kent Beck defined unit testing in the context of TDD. The talk [TDD, Where Did It All Go Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM&feature=youtu.be&t=2100) is very enlightening on this point.

Comment: Great link, thanks. There are lots of articles that advocate mocking ALL dependencies to ensure each test covers only the logic in the class under test. Therefore, the unit is the class. Interesting to see Kent Beck and also Martin Fowler (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html) are more open to, and have practised, sociable unit testing. In this case the unit is referring to a unit of behaviour that may span more than one class. With this in mind, I feel it would be reasonable to sociably UNIT test all THE links of this Chain of Responsiblity, without mocking them